# Add Caption to pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, standalone

I'm trying to add a caption to a plot made with `pgfplot`. The code is the following:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt,tikz,varwith]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/xbar legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
        \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
        plot coordinates {(0.8em,0cm)(0.6em,2*\pgfplotbarwidth)};}% <-changed
}
}


\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
    \begin{axis}[xbar,title style={xshift=-1.5cm},
    title=Figure 3..,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(1.3,.6)},
        anchor=north,reverse legend,legend cell align=left},
    yticklabels={Cat,Horse, Charly, Otto, Elisabeth, Fredy },
    xlabel={Happyness}]

    \addplot [draw=black,
    pattern=horizontal lines light blue,
    error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both,
    x explicit
    ] 
    coordinates {
        (10,5) -=(7,0) += (1,0) 
        (2,10) -=(2,0)  += (2,0) 
        (4,15)   -=(4,0) += (4,0)
        (5,20)   -=(5,0) += (5,0)
    };

    \addplot [draw=black,
    pattern=horizontal lines dark blue,
    error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both,
    x explicit
    ] 
    coordinates {
        (23,5)  -=(5,0) += (0.41-0.23,0) 
        (17,10)  -=(4,0) += (3,0) 
        (4,15)   -=(4,0) += (4,0) 
        (13,20)   -=(3,0) += (4,0) 
    }; 

    \legend{ Sweets, Playground}
    \draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
    \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{bla}
    \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Unfortunately the resulting output is split into three pages and I'm not simply getting the figure with caption on one page in the output. What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you using the `standalone` class?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Because I only need the plot, including caption to include it into a project not done in LaTeX

Comment: You could use `article` and then crop the PDF.

Comment: Agree with @TeXnician. However it is also nice to work with a standalone plot that can be conveniently and rapidly shared and that which contains more information than the plot itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using this figure elsewhere, then you should add the caption there, and not in LaTeX. Hence, you probably want to remove `\begin{figure}`, `\caption{..}` and `\end{figure}`, so you're left with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
<preamble>
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
<plot>
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You should definitely remove `[scale=10]` by the way.

But if you insist on having the caption, remove the `tikz` option from the class, fix the typo in `varwidth`, add the `capt-of` package, add `\setcounter{figure}{2}` if this should be the third figure, as the title indicates, remove the `figure` environment and use `\captionof{figure}{..}`:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,capt-of}
\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/xbar legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
        \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
        plot coordinates {(0.8em,0cm)(0.6em,2*\pgfplotbarwidth)};}% <-changed
}
}


\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=10]
    \begin{axis}[xbar,title style={xshift=-1.5cm},
    title=Figure 3..,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(1.3,.6)},
        anchor=north,reverse legend,legend cell align=left},
    yticklabels={Cat,Horse, Charly, Otto, Elisabeth, Fredy },
    xlabel={Happyness}]

    \addplot [draw=black,
    pattern=horizontal lines light blue,
    error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both,
    x explicit
    ] 
    coordinates {
        (10,5) -=(7,0) += (1,0) 
        (2,10) -=(2,0)  += (2,0) 
        (4,15)   -=(4,0) += (4,0)
        (5,20)   -=(5,0) += (5,0)
    };

    \addplot [draw=black,
    pattern=horizontal lines dark blue,
    error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both,
    x explicit
    ] 
    coordinates {
        (23,5)  -=(5,0) += (0.41-0.23,0) 
        (17,10)  -=(4,0) += (3,0) 
        (4,15)   -=(4,0) += (4,0) 
        (13,20)   -=(3,0) += (4,0) 
    }; 

    \legend{ Sweets, Playground}
    \draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
    \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}{bla}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice solution. There is an error in the code you provided, i.e. the part `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` after `title`

Comment: @PascExchange Oops, sorry. It's the markdown for image inclusion, not sure how it ended up there. Will remove.

Comment: @PascExchange ?

Comment: Ups, excuse me. Somehow I hit the comment key, although in the meanwhile I found a solution to the problem. Namely for really long titles one has to adjust the varwidth=... to an appropriate length.